# Does a CursorAdapter reset the cursor to the first position after using it on initialization?

Tags: android, cursor, android-cursoradapter

Basically I did not expect this to work but it does work fine:

```
    list.setAdapter(new MyCursorAdapter(this, cursor));     
    setItemsOnTheMap(cursor);
```

Both widgets, Map and List, populate the items correctly.
I thought that my setItemsOnTheMap private method would receive a cursor pointing at the last item of the result set.

Comment: what's the issue, If any isse then you can reset your cursor by cursor.movetofirst() after setting that use it in setIte,OnTheMap.

Comment: There's no issue.. It is just a doubt I have because I was going to do exactly what you mention but then I realized that the cursor is still pointing at the first element after creating the CursorAdapter. My question is, does the CursorAdapter reset the cursor after using it?

Comment: internally whats executed is not known to me. sorry i dont know